# Scala version of Wicket

Tags: java, scala, wicket, web-frameworks

I've read that there should be a (pure) [Scala version](http://scala-forum.org/read.php?4,10) of the [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) web framework. But I can not find a project website or anything else about it. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the related [discussion](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Scala-Wicket-Help-and-Advice-td3174601.html) on the Forum for Wicket Core developers, it doesn't seem to have been released yet.